# Generate PDF in PHP with Custom Margin

Tags: php, pdf, margin

I have jpg document that contains headings. Now I want to print values for these heading on that jpg document with a custom margin.

How to generate PDF and print these values using PHP?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to make a HTML document dynamically and embed that jpg image in it with all the heading values. You can create margins in that HTML as you want by some basic CSS. After that you can convert that HTML doc to pdf by using [mpdf](https://mpdf.github.io/), it also has custom margin setting capability.